Can Airflow running on a windows host in docker container access database on the windows network of the host?
I am running Airflow in docker container and can succcessfully connect to resources not protected by corporate firewall. I am not able to access any resources within firewall except for local folders in the host. Adding host network or bridge network stops airflow containers from communicating with each other. Is there a solution for this?
I tried setting network as host, adding bridge network, adding custom network with dns of the host.

Can you connect by IP?

No, I can’t. However a colleague using just a single docker container rather than a network of containers built by docker compose can.
